# Why this Button Command Binding is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, mahapps.metro

I did this like 50 times before. I really don't know why it is not working this time. I have a WPF application and my only dependency is MahApps.Metro. I'm using it's MetroWindow and Dynamic Style on my Button.

Here is the latest xaml:

```
    <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding ServerList}" Margin="5">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Border Background="LightGray">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" Content="{StaticResource appbar_monitor}" Command="{Binding VM.ServerSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Controls:MetroWindow}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"></Button>
                        <Label Content="{Binding .}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

Here is my ServerSelectedCommand in my ViewModel:

```
    private ViewModelCommand _ServerSelectedCommand;
    public ViewModelCommand ServerSelectedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_ServerSelectedCommand == null)
            {
                _ServerSelectedCommand = new ViewModelCommand(
                            p => { SelectServer(p); },
                            p => true
                    );
            }
            return _ServerSelectedCommand;
        }
        set { _ServerSelectedCommand = value; }
    }

    private void SelectServer(object parameter)
    {

    }
```

ViewModelCommand class is like RelayCommand. Here it is:

```
public class ViewModelCommand : Observable, ICommand
{
    public bool CanExecuteValue
    {
        get { return CanExecute(null); }
    }
    public ViewModelCommand(
                Action<object> executeAction,
                Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {

        if (executeAction == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("executeAction");

        _executeAction = executeAction;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameter);
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(() => CanExecuteValue);
        if (CanExecuteChanged != null)
            CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    private readonly Action<object> _executeAction;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _executeAction(parameter);
    }
}
```

Sorry for a lot of code. But I need to add them in order to find the problem which I can't see. So lets turn back to first xaml, that is the latest one I tried. Here are the codes that I tried for problematic Button line.

```
Command="{Binding ServerSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"

Command="{Binding ServerSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ViewModel}}}"
```

This also doesn't provide anything!

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Controls:MetroWindow}}"
```

Thanks!

Comment: I faced similar kind of issue while using Extended WPF toolkit with `MahApps.Metro`. Can you just remove `MahApps.Metro` and check whether the command is working?

Comment: does Snoop work with your app? so you can check your DataContext and Binding at runtime

Comment: I tried it without MahApps now. Changed MetroWindow to Window. It is not working. @blindmeis when I try to set a breakpoint at xaml binding it says "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code is associated with this line."

Comment: i mean http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/ this, but i dont know if it works with silverlight. usually when binding not work you just have to check DataContext first and Binding path second :)

Comment: I'll check that. This is WPF not Silverlight :)

Comment: Perhaps, [tracing](https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/) could help.

Answer (score 6):

This binding looks like it is looking for ServerSelectedCommand on the ItemsControl:

```
Command="{Binding ServerSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```

try this instead:

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.ServerSelectedCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"
```

Assuming of course that the DataContext of the ItemsControl is your ViewModel.

Comment: In my very first example you can see VM.ServerSelectedCommand. That is not working too.

Comment: VM.ServerSelectedCommand will definitely not work.  The items in an items control do not inherit their parent datacontext, so the button has no concept of 'VM' identifier.  I have used the answer provided by Peter Holmes in dozens of projects without fail.  Check your output window for any binding error messages and supply them for us.